# Getting "Syntax error" when trying to setup Jasmine2HtmlReporter

Tags: jasmine, protractor, html-reports-jenkins

Setting up Jasmine2HtmlReporter for my Protractor project.

Adding next code to my conf.js file:

```
    onPrepare: function() {
      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
        new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
          savePath: 'target/screenshots'
        })
      );
   }
```

And getting next error:

```
onPrepare: function() {
  ^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Below my whole conf.js file:

```
var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');

exports.config = {

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 100000
  },
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  directConnect: true,
  framework: 'jasmine',
  specs: ['specs/calbarSpec.js']

  onPrepare: function() {
      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
        new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
          savePath: 'target/screenshots'
        })
      );
   }

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');
exports.config = {
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 100000
  },
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  directConnect: true,
  framework: 'jasmine',
  specs: ['specs/calbarSpec.js'],

  onPrepare: function() {
      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
        new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
          savePath: 'target/screenshots'
        })
      );
   }

};
```

Put a comma after the "specs" key.